# Docusign Templates API taking much time

Tags: docusignapi

I am using docusign api to retrieve templates from docusign folder which shows in our app to select in dropdown.Now,We have very large templates in folder and its taking much time for api call.It's killing our performance.Do docusign have any caching support? Do docusign provides a digest API of some sort where we can hit it and see if there are changes and then not make the call if nothing has changed.So I can use caching at our end or any suggestion appreciated.

Comment: REST OR SOAP API?

Comment: You can store the template as json and "cache" it in your app

Comment: its rest api..I know i can store it as json and use it from cache.I was asking about docusign api ..quey params if any

Comment: how many templates do you have?

Answer (score 0):

you can use optional query parameters to limit the number of templates that you receive:
(https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/reference/Templates/Templates/list)

count   string
The number of records to return in the cache.

created_from_date   string
Lists templates created on or after this date.

created_to_date string
Lists templates modified before this date.

folder_ids  string
A comma-separated list of folder id GUIDs.